# How to fade in images one by one?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I have seen example using chaining settimeout to do this. However that would not work for indefinite number of images. 
The .each function called on multiple images would lead them fade in simultaneously. Is there any functions like .each available for looping that is blocking in execution?

Answer (score 6):

You can use jQuery `delay` method:

```
$('img').each(function(i) {
   $(this).delay(i * 400).fadeIn();
});
```

Comment: how does this do it one after the other?? you are counting on timers..you can prob pass a complete to fadeIn and bind it to the iteration count, so you'll now which img you use.that would be better IMO.

Comment: `i` increments with every subsequent image

Comment: I think it's not good to create a separate timer for each image. Someone can possibly use a lot of images.

Answer (score 1):

You should never use (or even think about) blocking methods in JavaScript. You can specify a callback for `fadeIn` method. It will be called after animation is finished. In your callback you can start animation of the next image.

Answer (score 1):

> "Is there any functions like .each available for looping that is
>   blocking in execution?"

No.

> "I have seen example using chaining settimeout to do this. However that
>   would not work for indefinite number of images."

It would work if the function would use itself as callback. For example:

```
var images = [ '#img1', '#img2', '#img3' ], index = 0;
function fade() {
  if (index < images.length) {
    $(images[index++]).fadeIn(fade);
  }
}
fade();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function fadeInComplete(i,$imgs)
{

  if (i >= $imgs.length) return;
  $imgs[i].fadeIn(400,fadeInComplete.bind(i+1,$imgs);
}

$imgs = $('img');
fadeInComplete(0,$imgs);
```